# increment or decrement calendar not working after inflate view

Tags: android, calendar

I inflated a view and i am setting text on each view with the calendar day but when i try to increment or decrement the date and set the text again or over ride the view it isn't working , in switch case i want to increment or decremnent and display entire calendar of that particular month

package com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.Screens;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.MainActivity;
import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.R;
import com.vedicrishiastro.kundli.datasets.Const;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton;

import static android.support.v4.content.res.TypedArrayUtils.getResourceId;

public class PanchangCal extends AbstractActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout[] linearday=new LinearLayout[42];
    View[] myView=new View[42];
    private CardView cardprevious,cardnext,cardcurrent;
    private TextView date;
    TextView datetext;
    private FancyButton location;
    private int CITY=101;
    RelativeLayout inflatedLayout;
    Double changedPlaceLong;
    Double changedPlaceLat;
    Double changedPlacetz;


    Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar changeday=Calendar.getInstance();





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal);

        date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.todaydate);
        cardprevious=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.cardpprevious);
        cardnext=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.cardppnext);
        cardcurrent=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.cardpptoday);
        location=(FancyButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCityD);




        String[] MONTHS=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month);
        int mm=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int yy=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(MONTHS[mm]).append("-").append(yy));


        for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
            int resid = getResources().getIdentifier("cald" + i, "id", getPackageName());
            linearday[i] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(resid);
        }


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // calculae length of month
        changeday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        int monthLength = changeday.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int dayOfFirstWeek = changeday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int date = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < 42; j++)
        {
            if( j+1 < dayOfFirstWeek || date > monthLength)
            {
                myView[j] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);
            }
            else
            {
                myView[j] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);

                datetext = (TextView) myView[j].findViewById(R.id.panchangcaltxt10);


                datetext.setText(new StringBuilder().append(date));
                date++;
            }

        }






        for(int k=0;k<42;k++){
            linearday[k].addView(myView[k]);

        }

        for(int l=0;l<42;l++){
            linearday[l].setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        cardprevious.setOnClickListener(this);
        cardnext.setOnClickListener(this);
        location.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    public void onClick(View v)
    {int id=v.getId();

        switch (id){


            case R.id.cald0:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald1:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald2:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald3:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald4:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald5:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald6:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:7", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald7:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:8", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald8:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:9", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald9:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:10", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald10:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:11", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald11:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:12", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald12:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:13", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald13:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:14", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald14:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:15", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald15:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:16", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald16:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:17", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald17:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:18", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald18:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:19", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald19:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:20", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald20:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:21", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald21:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:22", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald22:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:23", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald23:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:24", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald24:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:25", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald25:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:26", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald26:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:27", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald27:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:28", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald28:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:29", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald29:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:30", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald30:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:31", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald31:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:32", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald32:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:33", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald33:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:34", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald34:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:35", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald35:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:36", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald36:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:37", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald37:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:38", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald38:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:39", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald39:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:40", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald40:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:41", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;
            case R.id.cald41:{Toast.makeText(PanchangCal.this, "Day:42", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}break;


            case R.id.cardpprevious:{
                String[] MONTHS=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month);
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
                int mm=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int yy=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(MONTHS[mm]).append("-").append(yy));

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                // calculae length of month
                changeday.add(Calendar.MONTH,-1);
                changeday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);

                int monthLength = changeday.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int dayOfFirstWeek = changeday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                int date = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < 42; j++)
                {
                    if( j+1 < dayOfFirstWeek || date > monthLength)
                    {
                        myView[j] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myView[j] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);

                        datetext = (TextView) myView[j].findViewById(R.id.panchangcaltxt10);


                        datetext.setText(new StringBuilder().append(date));
                        date++;
                    }

                }




            }break;
            case R.id.cardppnext:{
                String[]MONTHS=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month);
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);
                int mm=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int yy=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(MONTHS[mm]).append("-").append(yy));

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                // calculae length of month
                changeday.add(Calendar.MONTH,1);
                changeday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);

                int monthLength = changeday.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int dayOfFirstWeek = changeday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                int date = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < 42; j++)
                {
                    if( j+1 < dayOfFirstWeek || date > monthLength)
                    {
                        myView[j] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myView[j] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_panchang_cal_inflate, null);

                        datetext = (TextView) myView[j].findViewById(R.id.panchangcaltxt10);


                        datetext.setText(new StringBuilder().append(date));
                        date++;
                    }

                }
            }break;
            case R.id.btnCityD:{
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),CITY);
            }break;

        }


    }


        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent intent){
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,intent);
            if(requestCode==CITY){
                String geoName=intent.getStringExtra(Const.GeoConst.NAME);

                location.setText(geoName);


            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For increment Calendar date**

`cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`

**For decrement:**

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
```